# Facebook Like abd Twitter retweet button - Yahoo implmentation

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm interested with the way Yahoo implement their Facebook's share and Twitter retweet button, 
as from the link http://shine.yahoo.com/event/the-thread/fashion-disasters-made-right-2444269

Any idea how can it be done my own website?

Comment: I've retagged the question as "html css" rather than "yahoo facebook twitter".  It seems to be just a simple html/css question.

Comment: @Dalin: Those Facebook and Twitter buttons are not static, they show a like and tweet count, which means they're calling some APIs.

Comment: I was definitely looking at the wrong buttons then.  The facebook button is a PHP redirect and the twitter button appears to be just javascript.  I've re-retagged them.

Comment: I discover the Yahoo implementation of FB Share button which has the url http://l.yimg.com/b/social_buttons/facebook-share-iframe.php?u={url}, any idea on the 'like' instead of 'share'?

Answer (score 0):

http://sethsandler.com/resources/combine-display-facebook-twitter-comment-counts/ -> explains how to get a url share count on facebook. I'm not saying this is what Yahoo! is using, but some API calls like these are being made to show the count along with the logo.